# Windows Phone 8 & Phonegap: how to close app with back button

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I use phonegap to create Windows Phone 8 app

Now, I'm done with everything but i can't exit the application with back button.
I had used navigator.app.exitApp(); but it's now working. 
Does it work on Windows Phone?

It's working on Android and Blackberry.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Someone please help....

Answer (score 1):

navigator.app is only available on Android and Blackberry.  To exit from the app in Windows Phone 8 using the back button you need to remove the back button event handler.

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.go(-1);
}

function onPageChange() {
    if(window.location.hash != "#/") {
        // add our event listener for sub pages, this will allow us
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    } else {
        // remove the event listener so the back button will exit the app
        document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
}
```